# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in play framework project

Tags: java, scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

Hi Everyone i was facing the below error
[error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
i was using play framework of version 2.5.9.
and java of version 1.7
please find my build and plugins file :

build.sbt

```
name := """getbike2"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
cache,
javaWs,
"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.2.22",
"com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "1.7.1",
"commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
"org.apache.directory.studio" % "org.apache.commons.io" % "2.4",
"org.apache.poi" % "poi" %"3.9",
"org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9"
)

jacoco.settings
parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v", "-q", "-a")
```

plugins.sbt:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.9")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(PlayEbean).
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.2")


addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.2.0")
```

Terminal log:

```
vave@vave-Lenovo-G500:~/Desktop/getbike/getbike$ activator
[info] Loading project definition from /home/vave/Desktop/getbike/getbike/project
[info] Set current project to getbike2 (in build file:/home/vave/Desktop/getbike/getbike/)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:559)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:559)
at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:157)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$.com$typesafe$sbt$web$SbtWeb$$load(SbtWeb.scala:573)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$globalSettings$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:143)
at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$globalSettings$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SbtWeb.scala:143)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:55)
at sbt.Project$.setProject(Project.scala:319)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:503)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:484)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:484)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:54)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?

So please help me how to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play framework requires Java 8 from version 2.4.0 and higher. You should update your Java to version 8 if you want to keep using Play 2.5.9.

https://www.playframework.com/changelog

> Play 2.4.0 “Damiya”
>
> Released 26 May 2015
>
> - Dependency injection out of the box.
> - Testing is easier thanks to better support for mocking.
> - It is now straightforward to embed Play in your application.
> - You can now aggregate reverse routers from multiple projects.
> - **More Java 8 integration —- Java 8 is now required.**
> - Choice of standard project layout.
> - Many new anorm features. Anorm is now its own project!
> - Upgraded to Ebean 4. Ebean is (also) its own project!
> - HikariCP is the default connection pool
> - WS supports Server Name Identification (SNI).

Comment: Thanks, luc14n0, I have updated java version from 7 to 8, and its working fine now.